# Who don't identical SVG paths line up correctly (with one is in defs)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have an SVG element loaded from an `<object>` tag.  This file was made externally so there are all sorts of transforms applied to it.

Additionally, I am resizing the entire element with CSS.

In my SVG image I have a `<path>` mask in the `<defs>` section and an identical one at the root of the SVG element.

Frustratingly, the mask is not where I want it to be and I am not sure why.  As a test, I created an identical path at the bottom of my SVG, (not in a group or anything), and the paths do not line up (even when everything in the paths is the **exact same**.

Is there some way / reason that two elements with the exact same paths and transformations would not be identical?

Are coordinates in the `<defs>` section treated differently?

Here is a simplified example of my code (the whole code is below this):

```
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="http://localhost:8000/assets/imagesvg" id="logo" height="160.75623mm" width="163.64865mm">
     <svg viewBox="0 0 579.85743 569.60867">
      <defs id="defs4">
        <mask id="mask3" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100">
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="my-path2" stroke-width="15" fill="none" stroke="#f0f" d="M 325.13558948214785 96.53577318284954 A 213.26045386528068 213.26045386528068 0 1 0 309.20001220703125 522.4604660723119" transform="matrix(0.938091, 0, 0, 0.938091, -0.128913, -0)"/>    
        </mask>
      </defs>
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="my-path" stroke-width="15" fill="none" stroke="#f0f" d="M 325.13558948214785 96.53577318284954 A 213.26045386528068 213.26045386528068 0 1 0 309.20001220703125 522.4604660723119" transform="matrix(0.938091, 0, 0, 0.938091, -0.128913, -0)"/>
     </svg>
    </object>
```

As you can see the two paths are identical, so I am not sure what the issue is.

Both elements are in the root of the SVG element so I would assume they are the same. The path **size** is correct, but it looks like the origin is shifted up and to the left for the `<defs><mask>` element. The amount by witch the paths differ are the same when the SVG element is resized with CSS.

**Full SVG**

```
<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" version="1.1" id="svg2" viewBox="0 0 579.85743 569.60867" height="160.75623mm" width="163.64865mm" inkscape:version="0.91 r13725" sodipodi:docname="knob.svg" inkscape:label="Layer">
  <sodipodi:namedview pagecolor="#ffffff" bordercolor="#666666" borderopacity="1" objecttolerance="10" gridtolerance="10" guidetolerance="10" inkscape:pageopacity="0" inkscape:pageshadow="2" inkscape:window-width="1536" inkscape:window-height="841" id="namedview12" showgrid="false" inkscape:zoom="0.44851478" inkscape:cx="-150.69173" inkscape:cy="425.05921" inkscape:window-x="3832" inkscape:window-y="-8" inkscape:window-maximized="1" inkscape:current-layer="layer3" fit-margin-top="0" fit-margin-left="0" fit-margin-right="0" fit-margin-bottom="0"/>
  <defs id="defs4">
    <linearGradient inkscape:collect="always" id="linearGradient6371">
      <stop style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:1;" offset="0" id="stop6373"/>
      <stop style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:0;" offset="1" id="stop6375"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <radialGradient inkscape:collect="always" xlink:href="#linearGradient6371" id="radialGradient6377" cx="185.47202" cy="377.83094" fx="185.47202" fy="377.83094" r="111.97905" gradientTransform="matrix(1,0,0,0.60178603,0,150.45756)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"/>
    <mask id="mask3" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100">
       <path id="my-path2" stroke-width="15" fill="none" stroke="#f0f" d="M 325.13558948214785 96.53577318284954 A 213.26045386528068 213.26045386528068 0 1 0 309.20001220703125 522.4604660723119" transform="matrix(0.938091, 0, 0, 0.938091, -0.128913, -0)"/>      
     </mask>
  </defs>
  <metadata id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
        <dc:title/>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g inkscape:groupmode="layer" id="layer3" mask="url(#mask3)" inkscape:label="Main Layer" style="display:inline" transform="translate(-73.492973,-42.944066)">
    <g transform="translate(11.564708,-126.05435)" style="display:inline" id="layer4">
      <path id="dialfill" d="m 211.42857,680.93363 67.14286,-92.85714 -64.28572,-62.85714 -18.57142,-78.57143 17.14285,-78.57143 82.85715,-75.71429 67.14285,-7.14285 57.14286,11.42857 57.14286,44.28571 27.14285,48.57143 7.14286,64.28572 L 500,510.93363 l -34.28571,44.28572 -18.57143,18.57143 75.71428,98.57142 68.57143,-70 35.71429,-85.71428 7.14285,-88.57143 L 620,353.79078 c 0,0 -72.85714,-117.14286 -97.14286,-127.14286 -24.28571,-10 -57.14285,-34.28572 -57.14285,-34.28572 l -102.85715,-22.85714 -82.85714,10 -111.42857,61.42857 c 0,0 -88.57143,125.71429 -84.285716,140 4.285715,14.28572 -5.714285,111.42857 -5.714285,111.42857 l 25.714281,78.57143 48.57143,67.14286 58.57143,47.14286 z" style="fill:#f3fc00;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" inkscape:connector-curvature="0"/>
    </g>
    <rect style="display:inline;fill:url(#radialGradient6377);fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;fill-opacity:1" id="rect-mask" width="222.9581" height="133.77486" x="73.992973" y="310.94351"/>
    <g style="display:inline" id="layer1" transform="translate(11.564708,-121.59518)">
      <circle r="277.14285" cy="449.50507" cx="357.14285" id="outerRim" style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#00f000;stroke-width:15;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"/>
      <circle r="158.57143" cy="445.21933" cx="355.71429" id="path4153" style="fill:none;stroke:#00f000;stroke-width:15;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"/>
      <path id="path4155" d="M 285.71429,586.64792 211.42857,692.3622" style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#00ff00;stroke-width:15;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" inkscape:connector-curvature="0"/>
      <path id="path4157" d="m 448.57143,575.21935 82.85714,97.14285" style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#00ff00;stroke-width:15;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" inkscape:connector-curvature="0"/>
    </g>
  </g>
   <path id="my-path" stroke-width="15" fill="none" stroke="#f0f" d="M 325.13558948214785 96.53577318284954 A 213.26045386528068 213.26045386528068 0 1 0 309.20001220703125 522.4604660723119" transform="matrix(0.938091, 0, 0, 0.938091, -0.128913, -0)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: In the full svg you have a containing `g` with a transformation that offsets the mask. Your simplified code works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/cttc6oaz/

Comment: You are right. I just figured this out! If you would like to make an answer I will definitely accept it, otherwise I was going to answer it myself.